# Angular UIGrid- UI Issues with injecting custom filters template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying inject custom filters (Angualr ui-select controls) using filterHeaderTemplate property.
Filter controls are getting rendered successfully but facing UI issues.

Filter controls are not visible properly.
[Plz see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5zkK.png)

As control is rendering in "ui-grid-header-canvas" element, because of overflow-hidden property it is happening.

But, when I added following styles

```
.ui-grid-header-viewport {
overflow: visible;
}

.ui-grid-top-panel {
overflow: visible;
}

.ui-grid-cell > .ui-grid-cell-contents {
overflow: visible;
}
```

grid becomes
 [Plz see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMP6w.png)

How can it be rendered properly?

Comment: It is better to replicate the issue on a plunker link and you can get the help immediately.

Comment: Your CSS generally applies to other elements on the grid messing up the design. You need to be more specific about only selecting the elements you want affected. It is difficult to suggest a solution without seeing some HTML. A demo jsFiddle/plunker would certainly help.